# When selecting several objects in viewer, what objects properties are shown in the properties panel?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to figure out what element the properties panel shows when selecting several elements. When selecting one element the panel showes the properties for this (obviously). If I ctrl + click and select another, the properties window change. But if I ctrl + click a third time, the properties do not change.

Is there a function I can call to get the element that is shown in the properties panel? Or can I assume that it's always the element that are selected seccond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the item with the biggest **dbId** whose properties are shown in the **Property palette** when multiple objects are selected.

More info here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/properties-shown-case-multiple-selection

Comment: Thank you Adam for investigating this. BTW I get a "You are not authorized to access this page." message on this blog post.

Comment: Not sure what happened to my post, even I cannot access it :) I'm checking with team to make it available again.

Comment: The article is back online! Yeah! ☺️